# What are common industry standards for creating game assets?

Tags: c++, c, game-engine, blender

I would like to gain some insight from some of you more knowledgeable game designers on what exactly the standards (or most commonly accepted conventions) for creating game assets (textures, models, etc.) are. Or rather if there is anything I have missed.

Here are some things I would like to know in particular...

1. Conventions for texture files.

   - Sizes (512x512, 1024x1024, etc.).
   - File type (JPEG, BMP, PNG, etc.).
2. Conventions for polygon counts of models (in a modern game).

   - What polygon count makes something a "low poly" model.
   - How to use a "high poly" model to generate a good normal map for a simpler model.
3. Proper way to design UV maps for an object.

   - Usually my unwraps look alright but nowhere near production quality. Is there a proper technique for this?
4. Proper way to generate normal maps in realistic fashion.

Also what would be some good applications for developing some assets. Particularly audio. I already use Blender for modeling.

Essentially I'm looking for the tricks of the trade, if anyone is willing to share of course =)

Comment: There's a stack exchange for game development: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I recommend heading over to polycount.com, a large forum for game artists. There's also the PC-wiki which contains tons of info about normal maps. This question is largely off topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: They are all game/genre dependent. End of story. Your game should be fun/interesting. If it isn't fun, assets won't save you.